# commit() for a single object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The following `save` function commits the whole store. How can I commit just `this`? `this.commit();` doesn't work.

*app.js*

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  save: function() {
    this.get('store').commit();
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a transaction, add a record to it, and then commit (or rollback) the transaction:

```
startEditing: function() {
  this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
  this.transaction.add(this.get('content');
},

save: function() {
  this.transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: in addition to that, setting `this.transaction` to null after the commit might be a good idea.

Comment: @FinnMacCool I agree. Here's a controller from an example project I wrote that follows this pattern: https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/contact_edit_controller.js

Comment: Sometimes I have problems with this approach, specially with `rollback`. I'm currently using `this.get('store.currentTransaction').commit() // or .rollback()` in the `Route` and I haven't had any problems since. This way I don't have to get a transaction instance from the store or have a method to start a transaction.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where I can commit a single object at a time. I tried the above solution but it commits ever dirty object and not just a single one. Any ideas?